# Single drive LVM to RAID6 LVM

Tags: lvm, software-raid, raid5, grub2

I cloned my entire LVM volume group from a single drive to a RAID5 array with 3 disks. The VG is formed by these logical volumes:

- root
- swap
- home

... and other volumes of some XEN virtual machines.

I tried to make the RAID5 array bootable using boot-repair from the UbuntuSecure disk. I get GRUB2 startup screen with the list of kernels, but the system doesn't start. It end up with some error message that tell me that it can't find LVM volumes:

```
Loading, please wait...
Volume group "lvm10" not found
Skipping volume group lvm10
Unable to find LVM volume lvm10/root
Volume group "lvm0" not found
Skipping volume group lvm0
Unable to find LVM volume lvm0/swap
Gave up waiting for root device [...]
```